# WiFi connecting automation on Android

Tags: android, python, automation, appium, selendroid

I am writing tests  via Python + Selendroid.
I am looking for way how to automate connecting Android device to Wi-Fi network. The product feature is: firstly we need to connect to X network, do something, and then connect to Y network.
Does it possible to implement using Selendroid or Appium? Is it possible automate? If it's not, why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve your problem using `adb` and `wpa_cli`, but your device must be rooted.

```
adb root
adb shell

svc wifi enable

wpa_cli -p /data/misc/wifi/sockets/ -i wlan0

add_network
set_network 0 auth_alg OPEN
set_network 0 key_mgmt WPA-PSK
set_network 0 psk "12345678"
set_network 0 proto RSN
set_network 0 mode 0
set_network 0 ssid "Qwerty"

select_network 0
enable_network 0
reassociate

status
```

For more information and examples refer [Connect to Secure AP using WPA Supplicant](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Connect_to_Secure_AP_using_WPA_Supplicant#Connect_to_secured_network_-_WPA2)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what i need. I have small issues with it: connecting to network was successfull, but Android system doesn't show it in Settings/Wi-Fi tab. But It is not so important :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to automate.I'm using Appium, so that i can use ANDROID 5.0.2 version also.

You need following things in your system

```
•   Android SDK
•   Java Development Kit 1.8
•   APPIUM for windows
•   Eclipse with ‘APPIUM-Web driver’ framework configured
•   Android device (> 4.2 version) and its respective device manager should be installed in your system
```

Im using that with java so i mentioned JDK